# adding child change the button bar tab from RTL to LTR

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

am using https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip in my app .. and its work just fine as i need .. i had 5 children in the buttonbar .. and my app is in Arabic RTL language ... the tab will be like this:

[image]

which is the right way to be ..

i have just added the sixth child and it got messed up .. like this:

[image]

how to solve this and make it RTL as it was? also is there is a way to make the tabs scrollable so it will not be so crowded and messed up like this?

Comment: Hello, I'm facing the same issue, I'm currently looking at it and will let you know if I come up with something.

Comment: Hi, I am getting same issue now, do you have any solution for this BUG?

Answer (score 0):

To get the needed behavior, one must the following:

1. Set the `semantic property` of your collection view to `Force Left to Right`
2. In the `override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController]` method reverse the view controllers array before returning it
3. In `ViewWillAppear` go to the last element of the array but make sure to dispatch to the main queue

   ```
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       if(self.itemsList.value.count > 0){
           self.moveToViewController(at: self.itemsList.value.count-1, animated: false)
       }

   }
   ```